# Copy files from source machine to LiveCD

Tags: linux, fedora, rhel, livecd, kickstart

I'm working on distributing a version of Fedora to our internal development team using Live CD.  There are certain files I would like to copy to the live cd that are not:

1. part of an RPM or
2. going to live in the user's home directory.

Based on samples I've seen I'm trying something like the following in the post section of my kickstart file, to no avail.

```
%post --nochroot
cp -ar /tmp/files2copy $LIVE_ROOT/files
%end
```

Where is `$LIVE_ROOT`?  Does it need to be exported earlier in the `*.ks` file?  Do I need to create the `files` directory using `mkdir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, my problem was simply that the directory didn't exist. This did the trick.

```
%post --nochroot
$LIVE_ROOT=/my/root
mkdir $LIVE_ROOT
cp -ar /tmp/files2copy $LIVE_ROOT/files
%end
```

Comment: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/install-guide/appendixes/Kickstart_Syntax_Reference/#sect-kickstart-postinstall

Answer (score -1):

The Fedora project has extensive documentation on [creating custom LiveCDs](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD?rd=How_to_create_and_use_Fedora_Live_CD).